# Why does friend function not able to access private variables of a class?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, forward-declaration, friend-function

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class base_A {
int a = 5, b = 6;
friend void derive::print(base_A);
};
class derive {
public:
    void print(base_A obj) {
        cout << obj.a << " " << obj.b;
    }
};
int main() {
    base_A obj1;
    derive obj2;
    obj2.print(obj1);
}
```

Though I've used friend key word I can't able to access the private variables. Anyone please help me on this.

Comment: you should include the error message in the question. The issue is not about accessing the private, but long before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need correctly to place declarations relative to each other in the program. Otherwise the compiler will issue an error that either a name is undeclared or a type is incomplete. For example

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class base_A;

class derive {
public:
    void print(base_A obj);
};

class base_A {
int a = 5, b = 6;
friend void derive::print(base_A);
};

void derive::print(base_A obj) {
    cout << obj.a << " " << obj.b;
}

int main() {
    base_A obj1;
    derive obj2;
    obj2.print(obj1);
}
```

In this case the program output is

```
5 6
```

That is as the name `base_A` is referred in the class `derive` then at least the declaration (forward declaration) of the name `base_A` shall precede the definition of the class `derive`.

On the other hand, the definition of the friend function shall know the complete definition of the class `base_A`. So its definition shall be placed after the definition of the class `base_A`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that **base_A** don't know that **derive::print(base_A)** *exists*.
Try divide definition and initialization classes